# Java Code Formatter for SBT

Tags: java, sbt

Is there any sbt plugin for Java projects for Java code formatting? 
I did a little search but it seems like all of the sbt-based formatters are for Scala's syntax.

Comment: not an answer to your question, but we'd like to add this support to ENSIME and it's the kind of thing that would be perfect for a new contributor like yourself https://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/issues/1402 (which could then be separated out as an sbt plugin)

Answer (score 1):

We have just released an initial version of the Lightbend `sbt-java-formatter` ( https://github.com/typesafehub/sbt-java-formatter )

You can use it by adding it to your `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.sbt" % "sbt-java-formatter" % JavaFormatterVersion)
```

and providing a `project/formatting-java.xml` file that is the exported Eclipse code formatter settings, for example like the [Google Java style](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml), and then tweak it the way you like it.